# Addid Static Report Titile on Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

i have faced  some  problem , when  i  want to display some static Title after i have displayed a few number of Rows . for Example , the first 4 rouws on crystal Report has header"Training " the next 4 rows mmust have  "Education " Report Header.

i am trying to display the report using by calling one Stored Procedures  any one who can help me please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert a new detail section above your current detail section and have the new section only be visible based on record count or some value in the data.  Add a new section in the details, Format Section->Suppress and enter a formula controlling when the new section is visible.  For example, a running total field named InspIDCount and this formula in the suppress section ({#InspIDCount} mod 5 <> 0) will cause a blank row every 5 records.  The new section could contain a formula to display the correct "title".

I think I misunderstood your question.  The number of rows for each type is probably not constant.  A better way to handle this would the to insert a group into your report if the data is not already grouped.  Group by the record type (Education, Training Etc).  You probably want to suppress the group header but show group by footer.  The footer could display a field from the database showing the type or it could display a formula (string) based on the record type.  It would only take a few minutes to give this a try.

Comment: Thanks  Harmon  the description   is a lot to me but could you be more specific  ..... i am kinda new for CR